# Dynamic Pivot query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I am creating a dynamic pivot query using SQL Server 2008 but got stuck in `STUFF`.

**Example**:

```
Declare @col as nvarchar(max) 
Declare @tablename as nvarchar(max) 

SET @col = 'STUFF((SELECT '','' + QUOTENAME(cola) 
                from ' + @tablename + '
                group by cola
                  order by cola
        FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
        ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
    ,1,1,'''')'

 execute(@col)

 print @col;
```

**Error**

```
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @col as nvarchar(max) 
Declare @tablename as nvarchar(max) = N'Table1'

set @col = N'SELECT
                  STUFF((
                        SELECT
                              '','' + QUOTENAME(cola)
                        FROM ' + @tablename + N'
                        GROUP BY
                              cola
                        ORDER BY
                              cola
                        FOR xml PATH (''''), TYPE
                  )
                  .value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 1, '''');'

execute(@col)
;
```

not exec @col

see: <kbd>[this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83fc0/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Meem, I have modified your query and it should look like this.

```
Declare @col as nvarchar(max) 
Declare @tablename as nvarchar(max) 

set @col = 'REF_REFM_CODE'
set @tablename = 'tblKeywords'
SET @col = 'Select STUFF((SELECT ' + ''','' + ' + @col + '
                from ' + @tablename + '
                group by ' + @col +
                ' order by ' + @col + 
        ' FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
        ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
    ,1,1,'''')'

 execute(@col)
 print @col;
```

See this [Demo in SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15508/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

Declare @col as nvarchar(max) 
Declare @tablename as nvarchar(max)

SET @col = 'STUFF((SELECT '','' + QUOTENAME(cola)
            from  '''+ @tablename +'''
            group by cola
              order by cola
    FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
    ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
,1,1,'''')'
execute(@col)

print @col;

**Note**:
i tried this and u check it once.

Comment: If I do so then again error `Incorrect syntax near ' + @tablename + '`.

Comment: add '' to QUOTENAME(cola)